# Remove empty folder from SublimeText3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have several empty project folders in the LHS folder section of Sublime.

I right-click and choose 'Delete Folder' but the empty folders remain. Restarting Sublime doesn't help.

I'd rather not un-install it if I can avoid it.

Is this a known bug in Sublime 3? How do I remove these folders?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove them from the project

[image]
<sub>(source: [wes.io](http://wes.io/YasH/content))</sub>

If they are sub-folders of another folder you have open, they will always show unless you specifically exclude them with  `"binary_file_patterns": ["folder-name/"]`